# Javascript Convert Extracted File from zip to new File() method in browser

Tags: javascript, meteor, fs

I'm having problem in converting the data of the extracted file from zip to new File() method so I can re-upload it going to other server. The main idea is that the user is allowable to upload the zip file however the system will only upload the zip files not the zip itself... So I need to extract first the files inside the zip and upload it to the server. I understand that it could be done by uploading the zip first and extract it on the server but the files inside the zip need to rename first with the appropriate name before uploading it and saving on the database.

I can extract already the file but my question is how to convert this encoded data below to new File() method.

[image]

I tried this:

```
new File([data], 'cc_causation_report.docx', {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', lastModified: Date.now()});
```

but it's not working.

Below are the full codes.

```
var filesInput = file;
var res;

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsBinaryString(filesInput);

reader.onloadend = function(e){
    var myZip = e.target.result; 
    var unzipper = new JSUnzip(myZip);

    unzipper.readEntries();    
    var myFiles = unzipper.entries;    

    let z_num_files_uploaded = 0;
    let z_temp_files = [];
    let z_num_uploader_files = myFiles.length;

    for(var i=0; i<myFiles.length; i++) {
        var data = myFiles[i].data;

        var name = myFiles[i].fileName; // This is the file name
        var _fxt = name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

        var bytes = new Uint8Array(data.length);
        for(var _i = 0 ; _i < data.length; _i++){
          bytes[_i] = data.charCodeAt(_i);
        }

        zfile = new File([bytes], name, {type: _MIME_TYPES[_fxt], lastModified: Date.now()});

        console.log(zfile);


        var uploader = new Slingshot.Upload("myFileUploads");

        uploader.send(zfile, function (error, downloadUrl) {
          if (error) {
            alert (error);
          }
          else {


          }
        });
    }
}
```

Any help are appreciated. :-)

Thanks!

Comment: What is `data`, how did you get it ? Are you in a browser environment ? If so, you don't need a File, a simple Blob has more browser support and all you can do with a File can be done with a Blob. (to set its name at uploading, use the third param of `FormData.append`)

Comment: @Kaiido, seems like you didn't read the details above. That is the data comes from the extracted file inside the zip. I don't get the point of your comment regarding FormData.append. I need to upload the extracted file going to s3 using Slingshot.Upload method and blob isn't acceptable by that function.

Comment: [Blobs seem to be accepted too](https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot/blob/master/lib/upload.js#L89) ; and while I don't know Meteor, I'd guess that you can specify a name as a property of this Blob. Also even re-reading your question, I can't see where `data` comes from. I got that it ultimately comes from a zip file, but what does the extraction ? What format is it? Can't the tool you're using to extract this zip content return Blobs (or Files...) directly ?

Comment: @Kaiido, I have updated the description, the data is comes from myFiles[i].data. Please refer to the codes, I've posted the full script. Thanks

Comment: So now it would be great to know which lib does expose this `JSUnzip` constructor so we can read their docs. But at first glance, `data` is an ArrayBuffer and you pass a string conversion of it to the File constructor. Why? You can simply pass the arrayBuffer directly in the File/Blob constructor.

Comment: And you say in a comment below that you've got an error about the type of the Blob returned by JSUnzip, what is this type ? How is configured SlingShot  's accepted types?

Comment: @Kaiido, here's the docs https://libraries.io/github/augustl/js-unzip. Some of my codes inside the loop are experimental only the real thing is I want only the **myFiles[i]** to convert to **new File()** type. thanks